# Grails 2.4.2 Domain will not save more than 8 fields

Tags: java, oracle, grails, intellij-idea, grails-domain-class

I am receiving an arrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when I try ta save a new record in my Grails app.

I have narrowed the problem down to only being able to save 8 fields.

Here is my domain class:

```
package nhvr

class NhvrJourny {

static constraints = {
    nhvrNo nullable:true
    journeyId  nullable:true
    width nullable:true
    vLength nullable:true
    height nullable:true
    rearOverhang nullable:true
        }


    Long nhvrNo
    String journeyId
    String title
    BigDecimal width
    BigDecimal vLength
    BigDecimal height
    BigDecimal rearOverhang

    String toString(){
        return "$nhvrNo $title"
    }
}
```

Im saving the data via a service. The method looks like this:

```
    def saveJourny(Map nhvrJourneyPars) {

    if (nhvrJourneyPars?.dateArchived)
        da = df.parse(nhvrJourneyPars.dateArchived)

    Map journeyPars = [
            journeyId     : nhvrJourneyPars.journeyId,
            title         : nhvrJourneyPars.title,
            nhvrNo        : nhvrJourneyPars.nhvrNo,
            width         : nhvrJourneyPars.width,
            vLength       : nhvrJourneyPars.vLength,
            height        : nhvrJourneyPars.height,
            rearOverhang  : nhvrJourneyPars.rearOverhang
    ]
    NhvrJourny nhvrJournyInstance = new NhvrJourny(journeyPars)

    println "journeyPars:"
    journeyPars.each{
        println "${it.key}: ${it.value}"
    }

    if (nhvrJournyInstance == null) {
        println "nhvrJournyInstance is null"
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (!nhvrJournyInstance.validate()) {
        if (nhvrJournyInstance.hasErrors()) {
            println "Errors: ${nhvrJournyInstance.errors.allErrors}"
            respond nhvrJournyInstance.errors, view: 'create'
            return
        }
    }
    else{
        println "No errors in nhvrJourneysInstance."
    }

    println "nhvrJournyInstance.properties"
    nhvrJournyInstance.properties.each{
        println "   ${it.key}: ${it.value}"
    }
    nhvrJournyInstance.save(flush:true)
    return nhvrJournyInstance
}
```

I can see the data that gets passed in and it looks OK:

```
nhvrJournyInstance: {"journeyId":"j1","title":"test","nhvrNo":"2","width":3,"height":3,"vLength":21,"rearOverhang":1}
```

This is currently returning an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when I call nhvrJournyInstance.save(flush:true)

If I remove one of the fields from the Domain class then the data gets saved. Note: while there are only seven fields shown the ID and version are being added automatically.

I have been testing using run-app from intellij 13.1.4 on windows 7
My Grails version is 2.4.2 and Java version is 1.7.0_60
The database is Oracle 11g using ojdbc6.jar

Can anyone shed some light on this? it is driving me nuts.

EDIT - Here is the stacktrace:

```
14. Stacktrace follows:
Message: 14
    Line | Method
->>  950 | computeBasicInfo          in oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    623 | getSqlKind                in     ''
|   1212 | <init> . . . . . . . . .  in oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement
|     28 | <init>                    in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement
|     68 | allocatePreparedStatement in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension
|   3140 | prepareStatement          in oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection
|   3042 | prepareStatement . . . .  in     ''
|   6022 | prepareStatement          in     ''
|    699 | $tt__saveJourney . . . .  in nhvr.NhvrService
|     58 | $tt__saveJourney          in nhvr.NhvrJourneyController
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
enter code here
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  Can you post the stack trace associated with the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?  The whole thing isn't necessary but show enough frames to get back to the line of code in your service.

Comment: the stacktrace goes exactly to the line:  nhvrJournyInstance.save(flush:true) in my service. That is what is so frustrating

Comment: Do you mean that the last frame in the stack is the call to `.save(flush: true)`?

Comment: yes.  I think it maybe the Oracle driver, as using the in memory DB works ok.  Updating a record, using the Oracle driver, works too.  line 699 in nhvr.NhvrService, shown in the stacktrace, is the call to .save(flush:true)

Comment: Your comment above says that the call to `.save(flush: true)` is the last frame in the stack, which doesn't make sense to me.  The stack trace which has since been added to the question above shows that the last frame is in the driver code, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with the version of the ojdbc6.jar file that I was using to connect to the DB.

I have downloaded another version of this file, which is 500kb larger, and it is now working.

thanks Jeff for your input.