# Grails GORM - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when switching from in-memory data source to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, grails

I have a Grails 2.4.3 app that I developed using an in-memory database. I am able to create, update, and delete data with no problem. However once I switch the data source over to our Oracle database I can no longer persist to certain tables in the database. Some of the tables work, which tells me that it isn't a connection issue. Can anyone help me find the cause?

Originally a fellow programmer thought that the enums might be causing the problem. However I tried switching all the enum fields to String fields with an inList: Enum.values() constraint, and it resulted in the same error. I also tried 'version false' in the mapping, but neither that nor the default works.

Example of a domain class that persists without issue:

```
class UsfCustomer implements Comparable<UsfCustomer> {

    /* -------------- *
     *     Fields     *
     * -------------- */

    String   name
    String   address
    Location location

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false, unique: true
        address nullable:true, blank: true
        location nullable:true, blank: true
    }

    /* -------------- *
     *     Methods    *
     * -------------- */

    int compareTo(UsfCustomer other) {
        return  name <=> other.name
    }

}
```

Example of a domain class that doesn't persist:

```
class Invoice implements Comparable<Invoice> {

    String      invoiceCode
    Vendor      vendor
    Location    location
    InvoiceType invoiceType // DI or CR
    Date        invoiceDate
    Date        goodsReceived
    Date        paperworkReceived
    Date        dueDate
    Boolean     applyDiscount
    String      invoiceComment
    Boolean     fromFile
    Long        batchId
    Date        interfaceDate

    static hasMany = [invoiceAccounting : InvoiceAccounting]

    static mapping = {
        version false
        invoiceCode comment: "Identifier for the invoice."
        vendor      comment: "Vendor for the invoice."
        location    comment: "Location for the invoice."
        invoiceType comment: "The type of invoice: debit or credit"
        invoiceDate comment: "Date on the invoice."
        goodsReceived     comment: "Date the goods were received."
        paperworkReceived comment: "Date the paperwork was received."
        dueDate        comment: "Date the payment is due."
        applyDiscount  comment: "Whether or not the discount is applied."
        invoiceComment comment: "Comment on the invoice."
        fromFile      comment: "Whether or not this invoice was created from a file."
        batchId       comment: "The unique identifier for the corresponding batch."
        interfaceDate comment: "Date the invoice interfaced to Banner."
    }

    static constraints = {
        invoiceCode nullable:false, maxSize:10
        vendor nullable:false, blank: false
        location nullable:true, blank: false // TODO - back to false
        invoiceType nullable:false, blank:false
        applyDiscount nullable:false
        invoiceComment nullable: true, maxLength:4000
        fromFile nullable: true
        batchId nullable: true
        interfaceDate nullable: true
    }

    /* -------------- *
     *     Methods    *
     * -------------- */

    int compareTo(Invoice other) {
        int i = vendor.compareTo(other.vendor);
        if (i != 0) return i;

        return invoiceCode <=> other.invoiceCode;
    }

    BigDecimal getOriginalAmountTotal() {
        return (invoiceAccounting) ? invoiceAccounting*.originalAmount.sum()  : BigDecimal.ZERO
    }

    BigDecimal getAdjustmentAmountTotal() {
        return (invoiceAccounting) ? invoiceAccounting*.adjustmentAmount.sum()  : BigDecimal.ZERO
    }
}
```

My DataSource, if that will help:

```
    dataSource {
        pooled = true
        //driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver" - this is what I used for in-memory
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect // this is not here for in-mem
        username = "username" // obviously I have a real set here
        password = "password"
    }
    hibernate {
        cache.use_second_level_cache = true
        cache.use_query_cache = false
        cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
        jdbc.use_get_generated_keys = true
    }
    // environment specific settings
    environments {
        local {
            dataSource {
                dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url = "ourURL" // obviously a real one goes here
                //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000" - for in-mem
            }
        }
        development {
            dataSource {
                dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url = "ourUrl"
            }
        }
        test {
            dataSource {
                dbCreate = "update"
                url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            }
        }
        production {
            dataSource {
                // dbCreate = "update" NO SCHEMA CHANGES DONE THROUGH GRAILS
                url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
                pooled = true
                properties {
                   maxActive = -1
                   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
                   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
                   numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
                   testOnBorrow=true
                   testWhileIdle=true
                   testOnReturn=true
                   validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the controller/service when I execute the save() command on one of the problem classes then it gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The stacktrace:

```
reached save
Saving invoice:[Invoice [invoiceCode=000, vendor=USFoods, location=Catering-Concessions Operations, invoiceType=DEBIT, invoiceDate=Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 EST 2016, goodsReceived=Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 EST 2016, paperworkReceived=Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 EST 2016, dueDate=Tue Feb 16 00:00:00 EST 2016, applyDiscount=false, invoiceComment=Testing, getOriginalAmountTotal()=0, getAdjustmentAmountTotal()=0, fromFile=false, batchId=null, interfaceDate=null]]
Error |
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.computeBasicInfo(OracleSql.java:950)
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSqlKind(OracleSql.java:623)
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.<init>(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1212)
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.<init>(T4CPreparedStatement.java:28)
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:68)
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3140)
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3042)
Error |
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:6022)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor275.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
Error |
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
Error |
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
Error |
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
Error |
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor275.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
Error |
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
Error |
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor275.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
Error |
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
Error |
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:527)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:131)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceIdentityGenerator$Delegate.prepare(SequenceIdentityGenerator.java:98)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:53)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2346)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2853)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.performSaveOrReplicate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:246)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:104)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
Error |
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(SavePersistentMethod.java:58)
Error |
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
Error |
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:341)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod.performSave(SavePersistentMethod.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:215)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:157)
Error |
    at edu.vt.es.dininginvoices.Invoice.save(Invoice.groovy)
Error |
    at edu.vt.es.dininginvoices.Invoice$save$3.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at edu.vt.es.dininginvoices.Invoice$save$3.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at edu.vt.es.dininginvoices.InvoiceController$$EPdASzSY.save(InvoiceController.groovy:71)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2.invoke(ReloadedTypeInvoker.java:122)
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1299)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:375)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:252)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:205)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:126)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:347)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
Error |
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
Error |
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter.java)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:178)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:144)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:135)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:216)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:181)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.IpAddressFilter.doFilter(IpAddressFilter.java:79)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
Error |
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
Error |
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
Error |
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
Error |
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
Error |
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
Error |
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
Error |
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
Error |
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
Error |
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The method I'm calling in InvoiceController:

```
def save() { 
        print "reached save"

        Invoice invoice = new Invoice()
        invoice.vendor = (params.selectVendor) ? Vendor.find(params.selectVendor) : null
        invoice.location = (params.selectLocation) ? Location.find(params.selectLocation) : null
        invoice.invoiceCode = params.inputInvoiceCode ?: null
        invoice.invoiceType = (params.selectInvoiceType) ?  InvoiceType.find(params.selectInvoiceType) : null
        invoice.invoiceDate = params.inputInvoiceDate ? dateFormat.parse(params.inputInvoiceDate) : null
        invoice.goodsReceived = params.inputGoodsReceived ? dateFormat.parse(params.inputGoodsReceived) : null
        invoice.paperworkReceived = params.inputPaperworkReceived ? dateFormat.parse(params.inputPaperworkReceived) : null
        invoice.dueDate = invoice.paperworkReceived ? (invoice.paperworkReceived + 15) : null
        invoice.applyDiscount = params.selectApplyDiscount ?: false
        invoice.invoiceComment = params.inputComment ?: null
        invoice.fromFile = false

        if (invoice.validate()) {
            print "Saving invoice:[${invoice}]" 
            log.debug("Saving invoice:[${invoice}]")
            try {
            invoice.save()
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            }
            log.info("Added invoice:[${invoice}]")

            flash.message = "Invoice saved successfully."
            redirect (action: "index")
        } else {
            render (view: "create", model: [invoice: invoice])
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post up the stacktrace. That will in fact help. No matter how deep it is (typical for Grails). Also, the controller code would be useful as well.

Comment: Have you compared the table permissions for the user account between the working and non-working tables? In fact, a good way to test this is to log in with the same credentials using your SQL query tool, and try some update statements.

Comment: Hmm, seems there's a mismatch between the H2 db created from your domain classes (I assume) and used in dev, and the existing Oracle db you're now trying to point at.  Or possibly something GORM can do with an H2 db that it can't with an Oracle db.   I'd be tempted to get a temporary Oracle db setup, let grails populate the temp db from your domain classes, then compare the temp Oracle db to your pre-existing db.

Comment: Please add version of Grails to your full stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I added the stack trace and the controller method to the post. I also updated it to indicate that I'm using Grails 2.4.3.

Comment: @EmannuelRosa Currently the app is deployed with the credentials of the schema owner of the tables (to avoid permission issues). Once I get it working I'm switching the app credentials over to a granted authority.

Comment: @railsdog Thank you, I'll give that a try today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the process of starting with a single field and adding other fields until it broke, I started to notice that it was the number of fields, not the type of fields, that caused it to break. With that in mind I searched and found this other post: [Grails 2.4.2 Domain will not save more than 8 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967846/grails-2-4-2-domain-will-not-save-more-than-8-fields)

The solution is to update the OJDBC driver. Previously I was using 11.1.0.7.0; now I'm using 11.2.0.2.0 and it works. If anyone can explain the specific reason why 11.1 was failing then I'll mark yours as the chosen answer.